# Using Click() on href Button HTML

Tags: java, selenium, href, captcha

I am working on a project in selenium, in which once it fills out a textbox, clicks next page, a captcha comes up. First you need to verify, then the captcha shows up. It is just a pop up box in the middle of the page and makes everything else unclickable with a white haze over the page behind it. Once the verification is clicked on I already have a method for solving the captcha.
The issue I am having is that with the methods I have tried, the webdriver cannot seem to find any trace of this button. I always get an `no such element exception`, when trying to use `click()`. I have tried `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();`, `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("home_children_button")))).click();` , I have also tried putting a `thread.sleep(Num)` instead of using a wait, along with many other methods on google. Then when I did some research about href buttons, I found people recommend to use `By.linkText`. So I tried that with all the methods I tried before, and element still cannot be located. I couldn't find anything else on google, so I thought I would ask for help.
I have attatched the HTML Code I currently am looking at for the button, along with the link for the website. Unfortunately to encounter this page, you must make an account. This page normally comes up once I put the DOB in. Thank you for any clarification provided.

`<a href="javascript:;" id="home_children_button" class="sc-bdfBwQ jXXvQg sc-kEjbxe hVNnSn">Verify</a>`

https://account.battle.net/creation/flow/creation-full

Code I have tried:

```
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("fc-iframe-wrap")));
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();
```

```
        WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("CaptchaFrame")));
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();
```

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();
```

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();`,

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("home_children_button")))).click();`

```
Thread.sleep(5000) //wait for it to pop up
driver.findElement(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();
```

Along with trying to use `By.linkText`.

Solution:
After being told it's an iframe, I looked closer at the HTML to see there was multiple iframes. So I waited to switch through them in order to click the button.

```
        WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/iframe")));
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/iframe")));
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/iframe")));
        
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, it is in **iframe**, you need to switch the focus of your driver to interact with **verify** button  :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("CaptchaFrame")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("home_children_button"))).click();
```

and once you are done with it, you may want to use `defaultContent()`

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: hm that still didn't work. I went through the HTML and found captcha frame, but webdriver still can't seem too.

Comment: Would the Id maybe be "fc-iframe-wrap"?

Comment: Can you share what code you have been trying ?

Comment: I have updated the post with what I have tried. Most of what I tried was messing with the `By` command due to it being a `No such Element Exception`.

Comment: I figured it out! I will update the post with how I got it.